# Join several strings

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-5

I have for example 3(or n) strings like this, with always the same length :

```
"abc                            "
"         xy                    "
"         xy   ----             "
"              ----             "
"              ----     xcv     "
```

What's the best way to combine these strings to :

```
"abc      xy   ----     xcv     "
```

Comment: How are these strings going to be available in the code?

Comment: Are the strings in an array?

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? A for loop inside a for loop would surely work, right?

Comment: What do you want to happen if you have differing characters? Such as: "abc   xy" & "abc   xz"?

Comment: @phreakv6: the strings are lines from a file

Comment: @JoshBeam: the strings are in a string var

Comment: @SteveBennett: best mean nice. is a for loop in a foor loop nice?

Comment: @TomBurris: string are always in this way

Answer (score 2):

Using `Array#reduce` and `Array#forEach` you can do something like this

```js
var a = "abc                            ",
  b = "         xy                    ",
  c = "         xy   ----             ",
  d = "              ----             ",
  e = "              ----     xcv     ";

var res = [
  a.split(''), // split intosingle character array
  b.split(''),
  c.split(''),
  d.split(''),
  e.split('')
].reduce(function(arr, v) { // iterate and generate character array
  // iterate each array element and set arr value if non space character found
  v.forEach(function(v1, i) {
    if (v1.trim().length)
      arr[i] = v1;
  })
  // return updated array
  return arr;
// set initial value as an array of string size  and fill it with ' '(space) 
}, new Array(a.length).fill(' ')).join(''); // join the result array to generate the string

console.log(res);
```

Comment: To clarify, if there are differing characters in a given column, the last character present is the output as long as it isn't a space. Great solution.

Comment: @TomBurris : it may depend on user need.... as per the code it will get the last non space character

Comment: @PranavCBalan: thanks for your solution. looks great

Comment: @pumi : glad to help :)